# Something similar to jMonkey Engine for C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, 3d, jmonkeyengine

I prefer C# as a language over Java, but I have been unable to find anything similar to  the jMonkey Engine for Java. I want the feature of just being able to simply add blocks (called Box in jMonkey Engine) to my world instead of loading models.

Maybe I am just missing something, but I haven't found anything similar in any of the C# things (OGRE, Axiom, XNA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although **XNA** doesn't have built in primitives you can use.  The [**XNA shader series**](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/shader_series5) is an example which has a bunch of primitives you could reuse from it.

Comment: do you think that will be efficient enough to have thousands of blocks on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Thousands of blocks still won't be using that many triangles.  With each box using 12 triangles each.  If you're really worried though you can use straight DirectX with C#.  DirectX has primitives you can use directly.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 1):

there is C# cheap good engine, but loading process working too long.

http://www.neoaxisgroup.com/